# Which is the better way to manipulate an image, using gd lib or using the FileReader() with Jcrop?

Tags: php, html, gd, jcrop

I am trying to resize and crop an image on a php page. I either want to use [gd lib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) with [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Which would be a better wat to go. what are the pros/cons ?

Comment: Try them both and then you tell us what the pros and cons are! :D

Comment: I have already used them both but for knowing the pros and cons i have to use them in a long run. I asked this question to get advices from users that are already familar (prof) to this. in fact more than %50 questions here in stackoverflow could have the same answer as yours. but most of them have more satisfying aswers. anyway thank your useful advice @Rasclatt :) .

Comment: Well SO is for code conundrums, and since there is no issue here and any answer you get will be opinion-based, the question is considered off-topic. There may be other forums in the StackExchange (maybe?) that would be better served with your question. I have not looked through them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jcrop` and `FileReader()` both are the frontend browser library or api,while
`gb lib` is the php backend library.

I have to two solutions FYI.

1. `jcrop`+`FileReader()` for user crop the image,and then frontend get new the cropped image's data like `{x:50,y:100,width:100,height:200}` relative to original image,which will be posted to backend for php process `gb lib`( `imagecrop` function).

pros: balance both frontend and backend performance.
cons: code looks more complicated

2. only `jcrop`+`FileReader()` for user crop the image,and them frontend get new the cropped image's base64 string,then post to the server.Server no need to call `gb lib` to crop.Just decode base64 image and save it as file.

pros: code looks more simple.
cons: increase frontend pressure. Save bandwidth (no need to upload original image)

Finally,up to you to add more logic in frontend or backend.